# Reset password in fosuser bundle strange behavior

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.1

I have a strange behavior on reset password. I installed on dev fosuser bundle. I override the login template and it's works fine. But reset route not works fine.
My config :

```
swiftmailer:
   transport: gmail
   username:  myEmail@gmail.com
   password:  passowrd
   spool:     { type: memory }
fos_user:
   db_driver: orm
   user_class: App\DesktopBundle\Entity\User
   firewall_name: main
   service:
      mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
   resetting:
      token_ttl: 86400 # change this value, it is in seconds = 24 hours
      email:
        template:   email/password_resetting.email.twig
   from_email:
        address:        noreply@acmedemo.com
        sender_name:    Title Email
```

I created a file : /app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Resetting/request.html.twig

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5" style="margin-top: 3%">

        <div class="title-area" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
            <h2 class="title">Reset</h2>
            <span class="line"></span>
        </div>

        <form action="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_check_email') }}" method="POST" class="comments-form contact-form">
            <div>
                {% if invalid_username is defined %}
                    <p>{{ 'resetting.request.invalid_username'|trans({'%username%': invalid_username}) }}</p>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Login" type="text" id="username" name="username" required="required" style="height: 55px;font-size: 20px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="right-bloc-pub" style="width:300px; height: 600px; background:red; margin-top:13%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I presed submit button I was redirected to the url : `/resetting/check-email` and error : `No route found for "POST /resetting/check-email": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD)`. And I don't receive the email. Can you help me please ? Sorry for my english

Comment: seems like you may be using the wrong action path, try checking to make sure `{{ path('fos_user_resetting_check_email') }}` is the correct route to use for that

Comment: Your form is set to POST to `/resetting/check-email` from the error it sounds like you have that route setup as a GET only. You may want to make sure thats correct then

Comment: In this case I'm redirected to the homepage with url : `/resetting/check-email?username=gfdgfd`

Answer (score 3):

You should create routing file in place where locate your bundle with userbundle.
For example:
**Application -> Sonata -> UserBundle -> Resources -> Config -> admin_resetting.xml**
The code from admin_resetting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="sonata_user_admin_resetting_request" path="/request" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:AdminResetting:request</default>
    </route>

    <route id="sonata_user_admin_resetting_send_email" path="/send-email" methods="POST">
        <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:AdminResetting:sendEmail</default>
    </route>

    <route id="sonata_user_admin_resetting_check_email" path="/check-email" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:AdminResetting:checkEmail</default>
    </route>

    <route id="sonata_user_admin_resetting_reset" path="/reset/{token}" methods="GET POST">
        <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:AdminResetting:reset</default>
    </route>

</routes>
```

Comment: sorry but I don' understand the idea